# How can i create two table with a single custom module in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I have created a table by a custom module.Now i want to create one more table with same sql set up.
I am using following code to create tables.

```
     $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->run("
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('menu')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('menu')} (
      `menu_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `parent` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `position` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
      `created_time` datetime NULL,
      `update_time` datetime NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
     ");

$installer->run("
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('menu_images')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('menu_images')} (
  `menu_images_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `menu_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `position` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`menu_images_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (menu_id) REFERENCES menu(menu_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");
```

When i reomve the second table,above code works fine but when i try to create both table with one files,it produces an error

Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

How can i overcome this problem.

Comment: Hey,I find the soution,I edited the code.Now it is working fine.I made the some stupid mistakes

Comment: you should put the solution as an answer and accept it: that would allow the rest of us who are trying to help you to directly know that the question is solved.